# Static Factory в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony3, static, dependency-injection, рефакторинг

Всем привет. Мне нужно в домене (в сущности) получать объект из базы данных.

```
/**
 * @return Money
 */
public function getAmountUAH()
{
    $itemsUAH = $this->cartItems->filter(function (CartItem $cartItem) {
        return $cartItem->getPrice()->getCurrency()->isUAH();
    });

    $amount = 0;
    /** @var CartItem $item */
    foreach ($itemsUAH as $item) {
        $amount += $item->getAmount()->getAmount();
    }

    $amountUAH = new Money();
    $amountUAH
        ->setAmount($amount)
        ->setCurrency(CurrencyFactory::createUAH())
    ;

    return $amountUAH;
}
```

Для этого я создал статический класс:

```
final class CurrencyFactory
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private static $om;

    public static function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        self::$om = $objectManager;
    }

    public static function createUAH()
    {
        return self::$om->getRepository(Currency::class)->find(Currency::UAH);
    }

    public static function createEUR()
    {
        return self::$om->getRepository(Currency::class)->find(Currency::EUR);
    }

    public static function create(int $numberCode)
    {
        if ($numberCode === Currency::UAH) {
            return self::createUAH();
        } elseif ($numberCode === Currency::EUR) {
            return self::createEUR();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Сейчас инициализирую фабрику в контроллере. Но это не то...

```
...
public function __construct(..., ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
...

    CurrencyFactory::setObjectManager($objectManager);
}
...
```

В каком месте и как мне лучше инициализировать фабрику? Может правильно было бы вообще пойти другим путем?

**Используется Symfony 3.4**

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что в целом вам просто подойдет проброс контейнера в entity?

Comment: В принципе, да. Но мне почему-то не нравится это решение.

Answer (score 0):

Пока сделал так:

В services.yml добавил:

```
CatalogBundle\Factory\CurrencyFactory:
    public: true
```

А в CurrencyFactory.php добавил конструктор:

```
public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    self::$om = $objectManager;
}
```

Соответственно убрал из контроллера строку инициализации.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу свое решение, для начала создаем listener

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class EntityListener {
    protected $container;

    function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();


        if(method_exists($entity, 'setContainer')) {
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();


        if(method_exists($entity, 'setContainer')) {
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }
}
```

Описываем его в services.yml для postLoad и postPersist

```
EntityListenerPL:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\EntityListener
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }

EntityListenerPP:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\EntityListener
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

Соответственно контейнер будет пробрасываться и когда только персистим энтити и когда получаем ее из бд и только тогда когда у энтити есть метод setContainer. Сервисконтэйнер можно соответственно заменить на чтото свое.